# Retrieving the comment that was entered while "Save & Comment" using API

Tags: component

We are using 2013 SP1. When a component is saved using [Save & Comment], it allows to enter the comment. But the comment is not displayed anywhere in UI. If I use *UserComment* property available in the Component object, the value is always empty. How can I retrieve the comment?

Comment: Not sure you know this, but Save & Comment is actually an extension, not part of the core product. Not sure it uses UserComment at all, or if the comments are stored in AppData.

Comment: Anyone got a reference to this extension?

Comment: I think it was (at some point) in the powertools. Chris Summers wrote it

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about the "Save & Comment" PowerTool?

In that case, the comments should be visible on the "Change History" tab that is also added by the same extension.

The data itself is stored in Application Data on the item with the Application ID 'ext:ItemCommenting'.

The PowerTools are open source and available on GitHub, so you can check out the code there if you want:

https://github.com/TridionCommunity/tridion-powertools/